# GoogleSheets : Array arguments to ISBETWEEN are of different size. =isbetween(11,$F3:F20,$G3:G20)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Error while using Google Sheets:
"Array arguments to ISBETWEEN are of different size."

`=isbetween(11,$F3:F20,$G3:G20)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggested array approach:

`=ArrayFormula((F3:F < 11) * (11 < G3:G) = 1)`

If you don't want a result for blank rows:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(F3:F&G3:G="",, (F3:F < 11) * (11 < G3:G) = 1))`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `ISBETWEEN` function will work with an array.

Try one line at a time:

`=isbetween(11,$F3,$G3)`

`=isbetween(11,$F4,$G4)`

or if you want an array:

`=arrayformula(if(11>F3:F,if(11<G3:G,true,),false))`

Adapt the `>` and `<` if you need `>=` or `<=`.

You can also limit the array range from `F3:F` to `F3:F20` if needed. Same with column G.